# Coworker ignores request in messenger, ask in person?

Tags: colleagues

Coworker ignores request in message app should I ask in person? I'm asking my coworker to help me with something for work in messagenger app. They are clearly online from looking at their status and don't reply, should I just take that as a NO or ask them again in person?

Request is to cover a task while I'm on vacation, I could handle it myself and it wouldn't take long but I'd rather not work on vacation. But I don't want to be that guy that pushes more work on other people.

Comment: If your company uses a ticketing system, use it. Provides traceability, and means that the request cannot 'get lost' in a morass of messages. I know of support people who just ignore shoulder tap messages, and wait for real tickets to arrive.

Comment: Maybe, your coworker overlooked your request in message app because he was too busy or multi-tasking at the time, and there were probably too many messages  or emails from many people sent to him at the time. You can try to talk to him via the phone or in person.

Comment: Yes, call them.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you ask them through the proper channel at your company.

Not sure about your company, but I have not worked for a company where the official position was that requests should be made through a messaging app.  If a messaging app is not the proper channel for your request then it is no surprise that your coworker would not respond.

> should I ask in person?

Assuming you have already followed the proper channel for submitting requests, you can follow up in person or over the phone, but keep in mind that neither of these leave a paper trail of your communications.  Even if you do follow up through either of these methods I would still send an email immediately afterwards summarizing what was discussed in person.  You should also consider copying your boss to keep them in the loop, in case they may need to intervene to get things moving along.

Answer (score 1):

So, I work in IT and sometimes, even though it shows I'm only, I've got our corporate messaging app muted because the notifications block part of my screen.

It really depends on how the other person works. Some people are very much a single focus type - Devs/Sysadmins generally fall into this category - and if you are in the middle of diagnosing a complex issue, it can be really frustrating to stop, deal with a message and then spend 5-10 minutes getting back into the groove.

Depending on what your field of work is and what they are doing depends - sometimes I'm happy to help with questions, other times the entire world can be burning and I wouldn't care as I'm concentrating.

Next I have to ask this - is what you are asking them for something you could find out yourself? Company Wiki/Confluence? Google? I know the frustration of working through something yourself that takes you 5 times longer than just asking that one person who knows the answer, but sometimes that is life.

Finally - have you talked with your Boss? They should have a rough idea of what your co-workers workload and schedules are like, if they have plenty of bandwidth to help but are just ignoring you - then your Boss can step in, whereas if they are busy and working to a Deadline, then you will have to sort it out.

---Edit---

In light of your edit - that you are going on holiday - this really should be a conversation with your Manager.

Let them know that whilst you are on Holiday, you will not be working - suggest the co-worker is best suited to handle this responsibility whilst you are away - but ultimately - it's your Manager's call as to who they delegate this task to.

Comment: Next I have to ask this - is what you are asking them for something you could find out yourself?  see edit

Answer (score 0):

> Request is to cover a task while I'm on vacation, I could handle it myself and it wouldn't take long but I'd rather not work on vacation. But I don't want to be that guy that pushes more work on other people.

This doesn't sound like a request that needs to be immediately handled. Longer vacations are usually planned in advance so there should be a couple of days to find someone to cover this.
Knowing this, I wouldn't immediately reply to it, even if I saw this message popping up in the messaging app, I would wait until I finished my current task, or took a break from it.

If you are getting ignored for more than a day, I'd ping again, and if time runs out bring it up with your manager, that you are having a hard time reaching your colleague asking them to cover.